# Why Gazebo's/pose/info is changing dramatically when robot is not moving?

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, pose, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

So I found in Gazebo that I can see a window with a topic ~/pose/info (I assume its the same as echo). So I have my sample robot sitting in its starting position, I havent moved it at all, however position **x keeps reducing** and **y keeps increasing**.

[image: image description]

Here is another picture to prove you that those two variables are changing when robot's position stays the same after around 10 seconds.

[image: image description]

Why is this happening? I thought this would show me ground truth data that I could use in calculations later on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232621/why-gazebo%27s/pose/info-is-changing-dramatically-when-robot-is-not-moving?/) by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem. It can be due to mass/inertia settings of your model's links.

You can also try to add these lines to your world file between the world tag :

```
<physics type="ode">
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
  <gravity>0 0 -9.81</gravity>
  <magnetic_field>0.000006 0.000023 -0.000042</magnetic_field>
  <ode>
    <solver>
      <type>quick</type>
      <iters>200</iters>
      <sor>1.3</sor>
      <use_dynamic_moi_rescaling>0</use_dynamic_moi_rescaling>
    </solver>
    <constraints>
      <cfm>0</cfm>
      <erp>0.2</erp>
      <contact_max_correcting_vel>100.0</contact_max_correcting_vel>
      <contact_surface_layer>0.001</contact_surface_layer>
    </constraints>
  </ode>
</physics>
```

This reduce the robot movement for me.

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1